# How to check if my database has changed?

Tags: javascript, jquery, mysql

I wanted to know if there is any method or way to get the response from server to client side that a row is inserted or deleted from database then show the remaining rows.
I tried a in a way that is will select all the data from the database after every 2.5 seconds.
I used setInterval() to call the method which fetches rows from a table.

```
setInterval(load_data,2500);
```

and the load_data() method

```
function load_data(){
    $.ajax({
           type: "GET",
           url: "data.php",
          success:function(data) 
           {
                $('#demo').html(data); 
           },
           error:function(data) 
           {
            $('#demo').html(data);    
           }
        }); 
}
```

the setInterval() is called when the page is loaded.
so instead of knocking on server every 2.5 seconds is there a better way?

Comment: Having every user connected to your site query your database every 2.5 seconds is an incredibly bad idea. If you need to keep the frontend in sync with the backend, look in to using WebSockets

Comment: well how to use WebSockets?

Comment: Literally the first hit in Google: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API

Comment: Google "Websockets for beginners"

Comment: Thanks for your answers. Dan & Rory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I have understood from your problem, that you want to know who has fired insert/update any record in your database. If you have allowed your users to interact with your database via front-end only, then there are two ways to track that:

**Method 1:** 
To insert/update a record in the database you have written some sort of query. Check if that query executed successfully then immediately make a method call to send you an alert message/email.

**Method 2:**
You can write triggers on your database to send the record in separate table and populate them on the client side where you can see which records are updated or deleted.

But query your database at regular intervals is incredibly a bad idea no doubt.

Hope any of the method will help you.

Comment: I think **Method 1** seems pretty much simple but brilliant. I will definitely try that

Comment: @Haque, if my answer solved your problem then please accept it.